# IVA space Suit leakage

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacesuits, sokol-spacesuit

1. What is the allowed suit leakage for Sokol suit at 
    40kPa/5.8 psi.
2. What is the allowed leak rate in IVA shuttle suits 
    at 24 kPa/3.5 psi.
3. What is the allowed leak rate from IVA suit 
    helmet

Comment: If the leak rate is small compared to the oxygen consumption of the astronaut in the suit, it should be acceptable.

Comment: Why did you pick 5.8 psi? Shuttle ACES suits operated at 3.67. Don't think what you want is available for shuttle suits at such a high pressure.  Also, "allowed" by what? Actual numbers may be available.

Comment: I have modified the values here. Earlier I assumed 40 kPa as inside pressure and 17 kPa as external pressure i.e. differential pressure 23 kPa only. Now I wrote it explicitly

Comment: @Uwe I doubt that uwe, because leakage is a factor factored in for deciding the oxygen tanks capacity. If leakage is more then it more oxygen need to be carried on board

Comment: Recently I heard heard from somebody that Sokol suit leakage is 500 CC/minutes (0.5 lpm). I just wanted to confirm if it correct, as for old US EVA suits the leakage was 0.2 lpm approx.

Comment: Oxygen consumption of the astronaut depends on actual workload and stress level and can't be predicted exactly. Reserves for emergencies are neccessary. Oxygen consumption at rest and 1bar would be about 0.4 lpm.

Comment: You didn't elaborate on what you mean by "allowed" Allowed by who? Are you asking for spec leakage?

Comment: @organic marble yes I am asking for the specified leak rate. Spec is required for qualifications of the items in leak test